# How to add a paper size to CUPS ppd file?

Tags: cups, ppd

I've bought a pile of non-stand sized paper. I am using a hp printer.
I've read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028891/whats-the-easiest-way-to-add-custom-page-sizes-to-a-ppd/3112256#3112256 but my ppd file is different.

> *PageSize A4/A4: "%% FoomaticRIPOptionSetting: PageSize=A4"
> *FoomaticRIPOptionSetting PageSize=A4: "-p9 "

So What does the -p9 means here, and how should I change it to add an entry of my custom size?